# A Particular Peg-jumping puzzle

Tags: puzzle

Many years ago I was shown this puzzle. It's a type of solitaire or peg-jumping puzzle. One places some arbitrary arrangement of pieces on a rectangular grid, 
below the grid dividing line (the *bar*).

Then you perform a sequence of jumps.

A jump is allowed for any 3 cells in line horizontally or laterally, and follows the standard
peg-jumping rule, ie: $X X . \implies  . . X$ (the center piece is removed).

The objective is to project a piece as far above the bar as possible.

For example:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\\hline
  \cdot & \cdot & X & X & X & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & X & X & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
  \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This layout allows one to project a piece up to the 2nd row above the bar.

It is known that, even with an infinite grid size and unlimited supply of pieces, it is impossible
to project a piece beyond the $4$-th row above the bar.

I was shown an elegant proof of this limit back in 1975, and my question is simply this - does anybody recognise this
puzzle?  If so, can somebody point me to the proof?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers

Comment: Thank you!!  I have been Googling for hours ...

Comment: Thanks Mike!  I'm a little rusty with the formatting ...

Comment: For more Solitaire Army Problems see: https://solitairearmy.isnphard.com/ 
This is one of my favourite https://solitairearmy.isnphard.com/11x11/forward.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of it is the [Conway's Soldiers Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Soldiers).

Comment: And thank you too!